# How to get the instance of a MVC Kendo details grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What I can't understand is how should I get the instance of a details grid. 
I have a grid filled with data. Expanding those rows reveals another child grid. At some point I need to add rows to this child grid without making it read from the back-end. I need to keep it strictly front end.

I can get the instance of any row from the master grid, but how can I get the instance of the details grid to make changes to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo saves widget instance using jQuery's `data` function on the html element a widget was bound to. After initialization widget instance is available via calling `htmlElement.data("kendoWidgetName");`

In your case, assuming that `masterRow` points to any master grid row I'd write the following code:

```
var nextRow = masterRow.next(); //Get detail row for current master item

if(!nextRow.is(".k-detail-row") || !nextRow.is(":visible")) {
    alert("Details are not loaded yet or are not expanded");
} else { //Details are expanded

    //Get details grid instance
    var detailsGrid = nextRow.children(".k-detail-cell:first")
                             .children(".k-grid:first").data("kendoGrid");
    detailsGrid.addRow();
}
```

Check out a fiddle: http://dojo.telerik.com/ikigo

Hope this helps.

**Update** - an example with an outside button:

In this case you can achieve selected master row using [`select()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select) method:

```
var masterRow = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").select();
```

And then find the details grid as in the first example.

Here's a fiddle with an outside button: http://dojo.telerik.com/ikigo/2

Comment: Yes, thank you this is of a lot of help, but I was wondering if I can do that with an outside button. Example: I have 1 global button, when I click it I get the selected row from the parent and add a new row to the child. Is there a way to achieve that?